# Android Emulator for CI/CD

Tags: docker, dockerfile, android-emulator, cicd

How can i create emulator with docker image for instrument test.

I have developing the android application. I have CI/CD pipeline and Docker Image for unit test and deploy. But I have instrument test for project. I want to run the instrument test over CI/CD Pipeline. I need the Emulator for this tests.

I want to create android emulator in docker image. Later I will call the this docker image in my CI/CD pipeline. I will start the instrument test when open the emulator.

How can i create emulator with docker image for instrument test.